# Why would a battery BMS refuse to function after cutting off the wires and reconnecting them?

Tags: lithium-ion, laptop

I tried to rebuild my laptop (Dell Inspiron 5537) battery pack with new Li-Ion cells so I removed the case, disconnected the cell wires and connected those wires to the new cells. After this point, BMS stopped working.

Is there any well intention for programming a BMS like so? One possible explanation I can think of is that if BMS thinks the voltage of the cells goes below the critical point for a Li-Ion (2V per cell), the recharging process may not be handled safely so it locks itself out to prevent any damage. Might that be the case? If so, shouldn't it unlock itself when it sees the appropriate voltage between the terminals?

Comment: Possibly. It could even be a deliberate anti-repair system.

Comment: Battery also reports its recharge count and **the remaining lifespan** (how could that be possible without a sophisticated BMS?) when the dealer connects it to his measurement device, so if this is a deliberate anti-repair system, it might also be possible that the BMS would cut the energy out after a pre-determined amount of time which would be possibly calculated by recharge count.

Comment: I've been bitten by this too. Laptop batteries appear to have some memory maintained by the cell voltage itself.  Lose that and the memory contents are corrupted, so the BMS shuts down. Not deliberate anti-tamper, but the same effect. I've seen advice to supply alternative power (from a current-limited PSU!)while performing the surgery, but it was too late to try that in my case so I can't advise if it would work.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I need to buy a new laptop battery nowadays so I was thinking about replacing the batteries without cutting the power first (first equalize the new cell voltage with current cell voltage by a 10 ohm resistor to prevent high currents, then wire the new cell to the BMS, after wiring all the new cells, cut the cables of old cells). Even it won't be cheaper way to go, I'll take that way and let you know ASAP.

Comment: Some BMS systems store a permanent failure which can not be reset even if the correct cell voltage can be measured again. This can be bacause of their safety concept or like mentioned above some kind of anti-repair. Some BMS chips can be damaged if the cells are not (dis-)connnected in a specified order because of high internal voltage differences.